# Graal-js is throwing File system provider error

Tags: java, pom.xml, java-11, graalvm, graaljs

I am trying to run simple code -
Added all the dependencies as mentioned in this document :https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo/blob/master/pom.xml

```
    ScriptEngine graaljsEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
    try {
        graaljsEngine.eval(SOURCE);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Still i see below error:

```
  org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
   java.nio.file.spi.**FileSystemProvider**: Provider 
   org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemProvider could not be instantiated

at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.loadInstalledProviders(FileSystemProvider.java:155)
at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider$1.run(FileSystemProvider.java:205)
at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider$1.run(FileSystemProvider.java:202)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.installedProviders(FileSystemProvider.java:202)
at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.FileSystems.findDefaultFileSystemProvider(FileSystems.java:205)
at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.FileSystems.newDefaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:100)
at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.FileSystems$LanguageHomeFileSystem.<init>(FileSystems.java:1057)
at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.FileSystems.newLanguageHomeFileSystem(FileSystems.java:112)
at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.createContext(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1584)
at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1627)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.createDefaultContext(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:304)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSBindings.initContext(GraalJSBindings.java:89)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSBindings.requireContext(GraalJSBindings.java:84)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSBindings.entrySet(GraalJSBindings.java:170)
at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.containsKey(AbstractMap.java:144)
at javax.script.SimpleScriptContext.getAttribute(SimpleScriptContext.java:158)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.createSource(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:401)
at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:397)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
```

Comment: share a sample app or reproducer, what you have in the source?

Comment: @MunishChouhan i was able to find a solution around it. posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : Bouncy Castle security provider was unable to register with JCE provider.tried downgrading the version of sshd-core dependency library to 1.2 for JDK11